# Is there generic MultiplyByInt?

Tags: f#, generic-programming

There's a generic function `LanguagePrimitives.DivideByInt` to divide by `int` without losing generic behavior, we can use it like this:

```
let inline Divideby2 n = LanguagePrimitives.DivideByInt n 2

val inline Divideby2 :
    ^a ->  ^a when  ^a : (static member DivideByInt :  ^a * int ->  ^a)
```

But there's no function called `MultiplyByInt` to perform generic multiplication by `int`. Is there anything to perform generic multiplication? Like this:

```
let inline MultiplyBy2 n = SomeGenericFunctionsModule.MultiplybyInt n 2;
```

**P.S.** we can always use some non-standard approach like:

```
let inline MultiplyByInt n m = seq { for i in 1..m -> n} |> Seq.sum
```

but I'm interested if it is possible to do in the right way.

Comment: The library cheats for the `DivideByInt` function and uses undocumented expressions which will produce warnings if you try to use them.  Coming up with a cleverer solution than your suggestion is tricky.

Comment: @Dmitry Have you tried my answer? It doesn't require iterations, so it will be for sure much faster.

Comment: Yeah, it works, thanks! But I've decided that this operation (multiply by int) is strange, it's not natural and confusing by design. In fact what I've tried to get is to get some constant of generic type when we have only `GenericOne` and `GenericZero`. So I've been interested not in multiplying something by int, but to get  constant of generic type via multiplying `LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne` by int value.

Comment: @Dmitry Maybe you can use the local fromInt inside my second function for that purpose. Make it global and don' t forget to mark it as inline.

Comment: Perhaps. But for custom types it wouldn't work unless we implement the `IConvertible` interface. It can be any custom type like galois fields or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no built-in function, but I can propose two alternative solutions:

```
type MulExtension = MulExtension of int with
    static member (=>) (x:float  , MulExtension y) = x * (float y)
    static member (=>) (x:decimal, MulExtension y) = x * (decimal y)
    static member (=>) (x:int64  , MulExtension y) = x * (int64 y)
    // More overloads

let inline MultiplyByInt x y = x => MulExtension y
```

But you'll have to specify each type.
I would rather use this function:

```
let inline MultiplyByInt  x y = 
    let fromInt (n:int) : ^a when  ^a : (static member (*) : ^a * ^a -> ^a) =
        System.Convert.ChangeType(n, typeof<'a>) :?> 'a
    x * (fromInt y)
```

I can't see any difference in performance between both methods.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get a solution in `O(log(N))` which beats yours, but it still feels very ugly

```
let inline MulInt (m:^t) (n:int) =
    let r : ^t ref = ref LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
    let addv : ^t ref= ref LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne
    while ((int) !r) < n do
        if int(!r + !addv + !addv) < n then 
            addv := !addv + !addv
        else 
            r := !r + !addv
            addv := LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne

    !r * m
```

Using some of the library only features could make this a little better, but would result in warnings.

Note: This solution assumes that `n` is representable in `^t` - i.e.

```
MulInt 2uy 5000
```

will loop forever

Answer (score 1):

```
let inline MultiplyByInt n (x: ^a) =
  let zero : ^a = LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
  let one : ^a = LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne
  if n = 0 then zero
  else
    let mutable q, r = System.Math.DivRem(abs n, 2)
    let mutable y = x
    while q > 0 do
      y <- y + y
      q <- q / 2
    let y = if r = 0 then y else y + x
    if n > 0 then y
    else y * (zero - one)
```

Comment: not quite right - `MultiplyByInt 3 3;;
val it : int = 6` - I think you are losing information when you do `q <- q / 2`

Comment: Thanks. It's fixed, although still not quite elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I've received an answer from Don Syme (via fsbugs email) when I've asked about missing `MutliplyByInt` and limited support of `DivideByInt`:

> Don's answer:
>
> This operator exists to support “Seq.averageBy” etc.  This represents pseudo-precise division of the total by the count. We didn’t extend the mechanism beyond what was needed for that.

So it looks like I've misunderstood the purpose of this mechanism.